# Could a traditional phoenix be resurrected after being dead for centuries?

Tags: biology, magic, mythical-creatures, mythology

In my novel I want my character to discover a phoenix. However, in my low-fantasy setting, magic and everything magical is believed to be long dead or nonexistent. To retain the idea that magic is a myth, could a phoenix be resurrected after being dead for a long time, and would this still classify this as a traditional phoenix, or would it be something else entirely?

The reason I am using in the novel for why the phoenix has remained dead for such a long time, is that the ashes were previously separated or otherwise stored in a way that would not make it able for the phoenix to be reborn.

To clarify, would a phoenix in a traditional sense be able to be resurrected if it has been dead for hundreds of years?

Comment: Well it's your book. Go for it! If I read that the heroes suddenly saw a pile of ashes turn into a pheonix I would not question whether or not it still counted as a pheonix.

Comment: One of the problem with Magic, is that "Magic Is Might"... well at least Magic is powerful, and can do anything. So the real answer is: yes, if you wish to. Your world, your magic, your rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if the phoenix hadn't burned, but experienced something like mummification? If the phoenix needed fire to be reborn, but for whatever reason was denied access to it, then "died" and dried out as kindling.

So the heroes come across a bird mummy, and through a series of events cause it to catch fire. To their surprise instead of burning away to ash it is reborn as a young phoenix from the flames.